# trying to make multiply divs in html dom with a forloop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

hi i am trying to make multiply divs within a forloop but the outcome is just 1 div. what am i doing wrong?

code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $hubbe.colors.length; i++) {
$hubbe.pallet = document.createElement('DIV');
$hubbe.pallet.setAttribute('class', 'pallet');
$hubbe.toolbarLeft.appendChild($hubbe.pallet);
$hubbe.pallet.style.backgroundColor = $hubbe.colors[i];
Object.assign($hubbe.pallet.style, {
width: '40px',
height: '40px',
border: '2px solid #2c3e50',
margin: '20px 0 0 5px',
disaply: 'block',
cursor: 'pointer',
});
}
```

Comment: You're only overwriting the `$hubbe.pallet` variable, basically discarding the previous `div` that was stored there. What do you want to do with the divs? Perhaps store them in a list? Or add them to the page?

Comment: hm if you look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517695/canvas-cant-get-color-pallet-to-work i am trying to make a color pallet for my canvas projekt but for some reasson i cant get it to work. this question was a follow up from my last post.

Comment: Ah I think I might have figured out the issue. From your other question, I gather that you try to use `$hubbe.pallet` as an array. The assignment you do in `$hubbe.pallet = document.createElement('DIV');` doesn't work like that though. Do you want to use it as an array? (list)

Comment: @NocNit yes i think that is what im looking for:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've told me, I think this will solve your problem. It changes `$hubbe.pallet` into an array so the rest of your code works as well:

```
$hubbe.pallet = []; //declares the array

for (var i = 0; i < $hubbe.colors.length; i++) {
    var temp = document.createElement('DIV'); //create temp variable to work with

    temp.setAttribute('class', 'pallet');
    temp.style.backgroundColor = $hubbe.colors[i];

    Object.assign(temp.style, {
        width: '40px',
        height: '40px',
        border: '2px solid #2c3e50',
        margin: '20px 0 0 5px',
        disaply: 'block',
        cursor: 'pointer',
    });

    $hubbe.toolbarLeft.appendChild(temp);

    $hubbe.pallet[i] = temp; //adds the object to the array
}
```

Comment: thank you this is kinda what im looking for but now i got an error say Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Comment: That might be because of the rest of your code. I noticed in the other question you provided, you also use `$hubbe.pallet.style.backgroundColor` in the function `chosenColor`. You have to change this to work with an array as well

Comment: oh okay yes i saw that it was at line 362. im not 100% sure how to do this tho im kinda new to js

Comment: Actually, I think if you replace `$hubbe.pallet` with `$hubbe.color` in your `chosenColor` function, it might work

Comment: Tell me how that goes. Also, if that fixes it and the answer helped you, please mark it as Accepted. Helps me a bunch too :)

Comment: yes ofc i will do that :) yes that got rid of the error tho it still dosen's allow me to change color haha. i think it have to do something with my eventlistenener maby. And im trying to get the code to add the active class to the current active color but that dosent work either yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171730/discussion-between-sebastian-andersson-and-nocnit).

Comment: I spotted those as well. I think the best approach is to make a new question for those issues. You can include the updated code too. I'm glad I could help you with this bit though